# What design technique to apply in order to match PC, tablet and smarthphone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

Until now I mainly made web sites suitable for PC (desktop) with help with Javascript, jQuery. Now I need to make some small web site **Tabular job time records** with menus, popups, dialogs, charts and the ability to input and modify data by click events (mouse or touch device) on table cell, plus additional statistics, math, etc. I started by making separate versions including jQuery mobile) but after some time it was very confusing for me to track all changes and understand such complex coding! Then I decided to apply some kind of responsive technique but after reading a dozen web articles I'm still unable to make conclusion what way is right!? Do I need to start web site as primary for mobile and then add some code for desktop, or opposite? Or is there some way, implemented does score for all three type of devices? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a little vague. If this question is only about the javascript interactions your answers will vary with UX requirements and libraries.  As far as layout etc is concerned, both bootstrap and foundation recommend you start with a mobile design to have the minimum amount of elements necessary for all the content, then add features and readability as you get more real estate.

Mobile first is simply a way to ensure that you don't end up with too many elements to fit on a smaller screen.

Comment: Thanks man. I always thought it's OK to start from big stuff, like desktop computer and laptop and then add necessary things to work also with mobile devices (tablets, smartphones) because it's more easier to test scripts in local environment (WAMP etc) than connect tablet to PC playing web server.

Comment: @LudusH You can design however you want. I've done both ways with varying degrees of success. Generally you'll have better luck by starting with the small screen since it's easier to add things than remove them. Feel free to reach out to me if you'd like to discuss this further.

Comment: mate, thank you for warm welcome to chat about possible jQuery issues I appreciate it. It's good to know there are people ready to share knowledge beyond borders.